# build issue when adding C function inside C++ in Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt, callback

I'm building a Qt/C++ app. This App must connect to an android device through MTP. during a mtp copy, I had to provide a C callback to the MTP API (C-only)

I have declared this callback is below:

DeviceMngr.cpp

```
int fileprogress(const uint64_t sent, const uint64_t total, void const * const data) {
    int percent = (sent * 100) / total;

    if (Transfer_Cancelled == true)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

DeviceMngr.h

```
extern  bool Transfer_Cancelled;

extern "C" {    
int fileprogress(const uint64_t sent, const uint64_t total, void const * const data);
}
```

And it's called in the method below:

```
uint32_t DeviceMngr::CreateFile(QString filename, uint32_t parent_id) {
...
    ret = LIBMTP_Send_File_From_File(Device->device, strdup(AbsolutePath), genfile, fileprogress, NULL);
...
```

The Transfer_Cancelled is used :

```
void DeviceMngr::CancelTransfer() {
    Transfer_Cancelled = true;
}
```

and

```
DeviceMngr::DeviceMngr()
{
    ...
    Transfer_Cancelled = false;
}
```

And also in the method instantiation to make sure it's init to false.

Here is the issue:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Transfer_Cancelled", referenced from:
      DeviceMngr::DeviceMngr() in devicemngr.o
      DeviceMngr::CreateFile(QString, unsigned int) in devicemngr.o
      _fileprogress in devicemngr.o
      DeviceMngr::CancelTransfer() in devicemngr.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

TransferCancel is only define DeviceMngr.c and any other place.

Any idea ?

Comment: you include several time the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the function, it's the variable `Transfer_Cancelled` that is the problem. It's a problem because you *define* it in the header file, and since you define it in the header file it will be defined in all source files ([translation units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)) where the header file is included.

You should only *declare* the variable in the header file, by doing e.g.

```
extern bool Transfer_Cancelled;
```

Comment: I have done this I have declared the Transfer_Cancelled in the same header but out of extern "C" {

Comment: I have changed the code in the description and also change the build isse

Comment: @Seb You still need to define the variable. Define it in one single source file.

Comment: I move the extern bool.. from header to cpp file but still the same issue

Comment: @Seb Keep the `extern bool Transfer_Cancelled;` in the header file, and in a source file add `bool Transfer_Cancelled = false;`. Declaration in header file, definition in source file.

Comment: Thanks it works. I use to do this but I didn't add the definition out the class. this was way...

Answer (score 0):

Add `ifndef` to avoid several include

```
#ifndef FOO_H                                                
#define FOO_H
extern "C" {
    bool Transfer_Cancelled;

    int fileprogress(const uint64_t sent, const uint64_t total, void const * const data);
}  
#endif
```

Comment: Include guards only prevents multiple inclusion in a single source file.